# MSDTC failed in windows cluster any idea?

Tags: sql-server, cluster

I have created a windows2003 cluster and then try to configure MSDTC by following the link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301600/#appliesto after follow this i have  enable network DTC access in Windows Server 2003

by following

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817064/

But the group i have created MSDTC( as said in first link from 7th point onwards ) for the resourse Distribution Transaction Coordinator failed and all are in online after done this. But i dont know why it is failing..

I dont know how to post the screen shot here.....

Comment: Have you tried deleting the resource and starting over?

You can also see logs pertaining to the cluster http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168801

Comment: What are in the error logs? Probably best place to start to see what is failing.

Comment: Have your tried using dtcping? Its really useful for troublshooting DTC issues See: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=2868 for a download

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the MSDTC resource, enabling network DTC access in both nodes and creating the resource again.

What are you using as storage for MSDTC?

Are there errors in the Windows Event Log after the failed attempts to bring the resource online? What do they say?

Answer (score 1):

The account using the FTC has to have full control on the cluster. Read on windows 2008; right click the cluster in cluster manager and select properties