# Windows Failover Cluster - Trying to create MSDTC Role - AD Permissions issues?

Tags: windows, failovercluster

I normally hang out in the DBA Exchange but I'm coming to ServerFault this time with a Clustering issue.

I am trying to create a MSDTC role for my Windows 2012 R2 Cluster.

The IP address and disk start up fine, but when the name A06SQLX-DTC tries to come on, I get two errors

[image]

Cluster resource 'A06SQLX-DTC' of type 'Network Name' in clustered role 'A06SQLX-DTC' failed.

> Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster
>   service may try to bring the resource online on this node or move the
>   group to another node of the cluster and then restart it.  Check the
>   resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the
>   Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

I believe this is a permissions issue, because on the AD, I am not seeing an object for A06SQLX-DTC. This object is however present on another AD where I did successfully create a MSDTC role.

One thing I've noticed, is that on the properties of the role, there is an access denied by the Kerberos Status

[image]

Which leads me to this article on [msdn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307532). But that has not helped.

Read this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/55815/msdtc-failed-in-windows-cluster-any-idea) as well, but didn't help either.

**Further searching in the Cluster Event Logs pulled up this**

Cluster network name resource 'A06SQLX-DTC' failed to create its associated computer object in domain 'mydomain.com' during: Resource online.

The text for the associated error code is: Access is denied.

> Please work with your domain administrator to ensure that:
>   - The cluster identity 'A06SQLX-CLU-1$' has Create Computer Objects permissions. By default all computer objects are created in the same
>   container as the cluster identity 'A06SQLX-CLU-1$'.
>   - The quota for computer objects has not been reached.
>   - If there is an existing computer object, verify the Cluster Identity 'A06SQLX-CLU-1$' has 'Full Control' permission to that computer object
>   using the Active Directory Users and Computers tool.

Here is my question:

1. What permissions need to be assigned to my login?
2. What permission need to be assigned to the nodes?
3. What permissions need to be assigned to the A06SQLX-CLU-1 object?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the problem.

The object in Active Directory that represents the Windows Failover Cluster, A06SQLX-CLU-1, needs to be able to create and list objects in its own Active Directory Container.

[image]

So the A06SQLX-CLU-1 is contained in a folder

```
mydomain.com
|
-----> COMPUTERS
     |
      ------> DEV
            |
             ------> A06SQLX-CLU-1
```

A06SQLX-CLU-1 will need to create objects/roles (such as msdtc, sql server) in the DEV folder.

Comment: +1 for striking a blow against the hated and dreaded MSDTC!

Comment: Thanks @Reaces, that was a very annoying problem. I was way too focused on my own AD permissions.

Comment: I can [sympathize](http://serverfault.com/questions/717505/local-dtc-is-missing-on-server-2008r2).

Comment: Hi Craig, we're facing the same issue, and even if we setup the right permissions, nothing changed. the Kerberos status error is still showing up and we can't add a listener to our availability group. Any idea how to deal with that ? (it's been a week since we're trying to figure it out :| )